# Saving a Date in a Grails Rest resource

Tags: json, rest, date, grails

I'm testing the Grails Rest Api.

I've created a Grails app with a domain class declared as resource :

```
import grails.rest.Resource
```

@Resource(uri='/books')
class Book {

```
String title
Date releaseDate

static constraints = {
    title blank:false
    releaseDate blank:false
}
```

}

I send a http post request to save a book using Chrome app "Rest Console" with the following params :

Body Content-type: application/json

Raw Body:

> {
>       "title": "The_book_title",
>       "releaseDate": "2015-01-01"
>   }

or

> {
>       "title": "The_book_title",
>       "releaseDate": "2015-01-01T07:30:00Z"
>   }

and I get a validation error : field releaseDate is not valid Date.

My question is how shoud I format my date in the post request to pass Grails domain class validation ?

I use Grails 2.4.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the default date format for grails is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZZZ`.

You can change this by adding the following to your `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = ['yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZZZ','yyyy-MM-dd', ...]
```

Where '...' is any other date formats you expect. Databinding should occur once your JSON date format matches one of the configured formats.